# how do you merge two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge 2 data frames

df1

```
Server      Model     Slot  Count40G
server1     Cisco     1      10 
server1     Cisco     2      5
server1     Cisco     3      20
server2     IBM       5      10
server2     IBM       8      5
```

df2

```
Server      Model     Slot    Count10G
server1     Cisco     1        5
server1     Cisco     8        10
server1     Cisco     4        1
server2     IBM       5        1
server2     IBM       9        5
```

I need merge these 2 data frames. The resulting data frame needs to look something like this:

```
Server      Model     Slot  Count40G Count10G
server1     Cisco      1     10       5
server1     Cisco      2     5        0
server1     Cisco      3     20       0
server1     Cisco      4     0        1
server1     Cisco      8     0        10
server2     IBM        5     10       1
server2     IBM        8     5        0
server2     IBM        9     0        5
```

merge on Server, append Slot, if Count40G does not exist on Server, on that Slot, insert 0.

I tried this:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Server", how="outer")
```

it is not inserting 0, any ideas?

Comment: This looks more like a `concat` operation followed by a `fillna`

Comment: Can you provide the DataFrame constructors of the inputs?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use all the relevant columns as keys in your [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
pd.merge(df, df1, on=["Server", "Model", "Slot"], how="outer").fillna(0)
```

If you further need a sorted output:

```
cols = ["Server", "Model", "Slot"]
out = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=cols, how="outer")
         .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
         .sort_values(cols)
       )
```

Output:

```
    Server  Model  Slot  Count40G  Count10G
0  server1  Cisco     1        10         5
1  server1  Cisco     2         5         0
2  server1  Cisco     3        20         0
6  server1  Cisco     4         0         1
5  server1  Cisco     8         0        10
3  server2    IBM     5        10         1
4  server2    IBM     8         5         0
7  server2    IBM     9         0         5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use concat:

```py
cols = ["Server", "Model", "Slot"]

print(
    pd.concat([df1.set_index(cols), df2.set_index(cols)], axis=1)
    .fillna(0)
    .sort_index()
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
    Server  Model  Slot  Count40G  Count10G
0  server1  Cisco     1      10.0       5.0
1  server1  Cisco     2       5.0       0.0
2  server1  Cisco     3      20.0       0.0
3  server1  Cisco     4       0.0       1.0
4  server1  Cisco     8       0.0      10.0
5  server2    IBM     5      10.0       1.0
6  server2    IBM     8       5.0       0.0
7  server2    IBM     9       0.0       5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge two dataframe on multiple columns. If you merge them with outer, then you will receive some nan values. So you need to fill nan values with 0 after merge operation.

```
merge_cols = ["Server","Model","Slot"]
merge_type = "outer"
filled_value = 0 

df_merged = pd.merge(left=df,right=df1,on=merge_cols,how=merge_type)

df_final = df_merged.fillna(filled_value )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**